# cURL to PoSH Conversion Assistsance

Tags: windows, powershell, curl, invoke-webrequest

I'm trying to convert a cURL command into PoSH so I can then use it in an automation effort.  I'm struggling to figure out how to handle the `-d`.  I've used PostMan to try and figure out which kind of body type lines up with `-d` but none of them really line up.  I know this is stupid simple but I just can't figure it out.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
curl -X POST "https://name.compname.com/page" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" -d "{\"dateFrom\":\"2022-03-18T00:00:00.485Z\",\"dateTo\":\"2022-03-18T23:59:59.486Z\"}"
```

Comment: Mind sharing your attempt? Also, Windows 10 comes with curl.exe if you prefer, no need to convert.

Comment: There are a multitude of examples using `Invoke-WebRequest` available. Please copy and paste, as text, the `Invoke-WebRequest` that you are trying to make work. Please include any error message output.